# How should I merge an index with header name in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge the index with header name. My data frame is like

```
t  = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b']})
t

    A
0   a
1   b
```

But the desired output is

```
    A_0     A_1
0   a       b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `unstack()` , then transpose , then join the multiindex columns:

```
final=t.unstack().to_frame().T
final.columns=['_'.join(map(str,i)) for i in final.columns]
print(final)
```

---

```
  A_0 A_1
0   a   b
```

Comment: I was about to post the same verbatim answer with even variable names :)

Comment: @iDrwish aha..co-incidence ;)